# MyBatis - dynamic <bind> variable

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

I'm facing an issue with my  variable in MyBatis select query taking its value from the outside. Like the below code

```
SELECT
            <bind name="checkRolePrice" value="true"/>  // this line is current form. I want to set value from outside in here
            <bind name="checkRolePrice" value="checkRolePrice"/> // something like that, or #{checkRolePrice}
            
            <include refid="digitalAppPlanBaseColumns">
                <property name="prefix" value=""/>
            </include>,

            da.ICON_URL,
            da.CATEGORY_ID,
            da.TYPE,
...
```

```
List<DigitalAppPlanWrapper> getAllDigitalApps(@Param("role") String roleName,
                                              @Param("deviceType") String source,
                                              @Param("planIds") List<Long> planIds,
                                              @Param("trial") Integer trial, 
                                              @Param("checkRolePrice") boolean checkRolePrice);
```

I want to derive `checkRolePrice` bind-variable's value from the method's parameter.

Details:

- MyBatis starter version: 3.0.1
- Spring Boot: 3.0.4
- Java: 17

I tried to use two if tags to get the result. It worked, but I'm looking for a more readable and simple way to achieve that.

EDIT V1:

I use this `<bind>` to define which column I will choose inside `<include>` block. I can't use the method parameter inside `<include>` block. That's why I have to use `<bind>` variable.

```
<sql id="digitalAppPlanBaseColumns">
        dap.ID                      ${prefix}ID,
        dap.APP_ID                  ${prefix}APP_ID,
        <if test="checkRolePrice">
            CASE WHEN dapr.role_price is not null
                THEN dapr.role_price
                ELSE dap.price
            end                     ${prefix}PRICE,
        </if>
        <if test="!checkRolePrice">
            dap.PRICE               ${prefix}PRICE,
        </if>
...
```

This solution seems a little bit weird.
I used the role parameter instead of a new one.

```
SELECT
        <if test="role != null">
            <bind name="checkRolePrice" value="true"/>
        </if>
        <if test="role == null">
            <bind name="checkRolePrice" value="false"/>
        </if>
```

#### THE SOLUTION:

I used `_parameter`, and it worked.

[doc](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html#bind)

`<bind name="checkRolePrice" value="_parameter.role!=null"/>`

Comment: It's unclear why `<bind>` is necessary. If it's passed as a method parameter, you should be able to use it directly. Showing the `<if>` version might help us understand the issue.

Comment: There seems to be `when ... otherwise` tags: https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html#choose-when-otherwise - maybe you can try it.

Comment: or use `_parameter` : https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html#bind

Comment: @HamidSultanzadeh You can use parameter inside `<include>`.  If it does not work, there must be another problem. If you need further help, try creating a small demo project like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues). If the same problem reproduces with the demo project, share it on GitHub or somewhere so that we can take a look. Be sure to make the demo as simple as possible (i.e. minimum number of columns, parameters, etc.).

Comment: @Vüsal, thanks a lot. _parameter worked!